# String pattern to regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongodb to store data. I would like to store complete regular expressions as strings:

```
{
  permissions: [{
    resName: '/user[1-5]/ig',
    isRegex: true
  }]
}
```

I know there is the module `mongoose-regexp` which can store RegExp, but I would like to store regex and strings in the same field.

I've achieved it using `eval(user.permissions[i].resName).test(resName)`. I would like to know if this is the correct approach and if there is any alternative (i.e. using `new RegExp(...)`)

**EDIT**

I'm trying to avoid `eval` as this field is comming from user input and it could be a problem if something malitious is sent to db.

Comment: You could use `new RegExp` but you'd need to remove the delimiters (`/`) and separate the flags (`ig`)

Comment: Or parse them out ... with a regex.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you there

```js
const rxFinder = /^\/(.+)\/((g|i|m|u|y)*)$/
const resName = '/user[1-5]/ig'

const resRx = new RegExp(...rxFinder.exec(resName).slice(1))

console.info(resRx)

const testStrings = ['String for User5, eh', 'Bad User7 string']

testStrings.forEach(str => {
  console.info(JSON.stringify(str), 'is a match:', resRx.test(str))
})
```

Comment: This version will fail if there are no flags.  You might want to make those optional.

Comment: `const matches = /^\/(.+)\/([a-z]*)$/g.exec(resName);` maybe could work, then `new RegExp(matches[0], matches[1]);`, this way the flags will also be conserved

Comment: @Miquel not sure what you mean there

Comment: @Miquel I have no idea about speed but you know what they say... http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Thanks, so it means it's better to use `new RegExp(matches[0], matches[1]);` or the solution you posted?

Comment: @Phil I see that there are also Uppercase moddifiers, so maybe the good solution for `rxFinder` would be `/^\/(.+)\/([a-zA-Z]*)$/g`. Regarding speed, if I understand well is it better to use `new RegExp(matches[0], matches[1]);`?

Comment: @Miquel according to the [docs for JavaScript's `RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), the flags are limited to `gimuy`